# How to scale down the UI size in ExtJS crisp theme

Tags: extjs, extjs5

Comparing Extjs crisp and classic themes, apart from styling, the there is a difference with size / scale of ui.
The Crisp theme looks its zoomed up 110% of classic.

Is it possible to scale down the size of crisp theme to that of classic ?
I realize that with styling comes padding, borders and image sizes which would be set for compoentns under each theme. 
But i would still like to know if scaling down the size is possible ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the font size is larger (13px in crisp, 12px in classic), plus each them is using a different font scheme, which will add a bit of a difference as well.

To your question of scaling down the font size, the answer, of course, is yes this is possible. You could go down a bad road of creating a bunch of CSS rules to override what's already in crisp, and that would certainly work.

However, the better option would be to create your own theme altogether. You could create a theme that extends crisp, and then simply tweak the various areas that you want to be different (font sizes, paddings on different components, etc). If you do this, keep in mind that the crisp theme extends the neptune theme, while classic only extends neutral (which neptune also extends). I say this because if you look at the actual crisp theme, it's pretty bare in terms of the things you're looking to tweak (padding, margins, etc). That's because the majority of these derive from the neptune theme, so you'll probably do yourself a favor to become acquainted with both themes in order to most efficiently achieve the result you're after.

If you've not done a custom Ext JS theme before, be sure to check out the guide here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/core_concepts/theming.html. This guide also has a nice chart that illustrates the theme inheritance for the default theme packages, so be sure to take a look at that as well.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, I had my thoughts on similar lines and I had tried out the theming guide by sencha. Just that I wanted to know if scaling was possible.